# Multiline trimming

Tags: linux, unix, sed, awk

I have a html file that I want to trim. I want to remove a section from the beginning all the way to a given string, and from another string to the end. How do I do that, preferably using sed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With GNU `sed`:

```
sed '/mark1/,/mark2/d;/mark3/,$d'
```

this

```
abc
def
mark1
ghi
jkl
mno
mark2
pqr
stu
mark3
vwx
yz
```

becomes

```
abc
def
pqr
stu
```

Comment: Would add that it's only working with properly formatted (pattern starts and ends on the same line!) html files.

Comment: That's true and normally html should be manipulated with a robust library tool (and luck and wind direction are also involved).

Answer (score 0):

you can use awk

```
$ cat file
mark1 dsf
abc
def
before  mark2 after
blah mark1
ghi
jkl
mno
wirds mark2 here
pqr
stu
mark3
vwx
yz

$ awk -vRS="mark2" '/mark1/{gsub("mark1.*","")}/mark3/{ gsub("mark3.*","");print;f=1 } !f ' file

 after
blah
 here
pqr
stu
```